# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on ionic build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Its my first time building an ionic app build via a Mac and its showing me flames. I have followed steps on the ionic page to do setup and build but for some reason I am having issues.

When I run `ionic Cordova build iOS --prod --release`

This is the error below:

```
Wrote out iOS Bundle Version "1.3.8" to /Users/admin/Development/App/platforms/iOS/App/App-Info.plist
Set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to "11.0".
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "App")
Updating icons at platforms/iOS/App/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
Updating launch storyboard images at platforms/iOS/App/Images.xcassets/LaunchStoryboard.imageset/
Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
Updating Background Color color set Contents.json
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-add-swift-support for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/src/add-swift-support.js
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Running command: xcodebuild -version
Command finished with error code 0: xcodebuild -version
Running command: ioreg -p IOUSB -l
Command finished with error code 0: ioreg -p,IOUSB,-l
Running command: xcrun simctl list --json
Command finished with error code 0: xcrun simctl,list,--json
Running command: xcrun simctl list --json
Command finished with error code 0: xcrun simctl,list,--json
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /Users/admin/Development/App/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/build.js:145:60
    at _fulfilled (/Users/admin/Development/App/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/admin/Development/App/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/admin/Development/App/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/admin/Development/App/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/admin/Development/App/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/admin/Development/App/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build ios --release --verbose exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +0ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +42ms
```

I have tried to do a build on a new project and samething happened. I did a build for android and its working fine on a windows machine I was doing dev on for the project.

Here is my ionic info data

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1100.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.0.7
   @angular/cli                  : 11.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.11.3
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v14.15.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.10
   OS         : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode      : Xcode 12.3 Build version 12C33
```

Thanks

Comment: And what is the particular command that is failing at /Users/admin/Development/App/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/build.js at line 145?

Comment: Run the command with `--verbose`. What do you need the `cordova-plugin-add-swift-support` plugin for ?

Comment: Hi @E.Maggini, here is line 144 - 145 ```return getDefaultSimulatorTarget().then(defaultTarget => {
                            emulatorTarget = defaultTarget.name;```...